# Show $(\{f\in\Bbb Q(\sqrt{7})^{\Bbb Q(\sqrt{7})}|f\text{ one-to-one and onto s.t. }f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\},\circ)$ is a group.

Tags: group-theory

I need to determine if the given set is a group.

{$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}) \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}) |$ f is one-to-one and onto and $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$} with respect to composition.

I know I need to show closure, associativity, existence of an identity, and existence of an inverse but I'm really not sure how.  The chapter gives no examples and we only discussed theorems in the lecture.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $G$ as the group.

### Closure

Let $f$ and $g$ be elements of $G$.

Then, $f \circ g$ is also bijective.

$(f \circ g)(x+y) = f(g(x+y)) = f(g(x)+g(y)) = f(g(x)) + f(g(y)) = (f \circ g)(x) + (f \circ g)(y)$.

Therefore, $(f \circ g)$ is also an element of $G$.

### Associativity

Follows from associativity of composition.

### Identity

The identity is the identity mapping $id(x) = x$.

Let $f$ be another function in $G$.

Then, $(id \circ f)(x) = id(f(x)) = f(x)$ and $(f \circ id)(x) = f(id(x)) = f(x)$.

Therefore, $id$ is an identity.

### Inverse

Since $f$ is bijective, $f^{-1}$ exists.

Let $F = f^{-1}(x+y)$, $X = f^{-1}(x)$, and $Y = f^{-1}(y)$.

We need to show that $F=X+Y$.

We know $f(F) = x+y = f(X)+f(Y) = f(X+Y)$.

$F=X+Y$ follows from the bijectivity of $f$.

Comment: Sure $f^{-1}$ exists as a map, but the crucial point is to show it preserves the addition.

Comment: @ancientmathematician sorry, I've added the proof.

Comment: I didn't doubt that you could; it was just that I have read so many fake proofs of this step that I think it's worth b eing explicit here!

Comment: @ancientmathematician what do those fake proofs look like?

Comment: They are not explicit about the ontoness of $f$ and so only prove $f^{-1}$ linear on $f(X)$.

Comment: Or worse prove $f$ is linear on $f^{-1}(Y)$. But let us not speak of these things.

Comment: I guess I am just confused about how to even get started with putting everything in the correct form.  I know $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})={a+b\sqrt{7}|a,b \in \mathbb{Q})$.

Comment: Sorry not sure why my latex isn't posting correctly in my comment.